# Npm Package msnodesqlv8 is not working on linux

Tags: sql-server, linux

Not able to install msnodesqlv8 on linux. I get this error when I'm trying to test my connection on Linux Server. Getting the below error.

```
Unsupported platform for msnodesqlv8@0.4.5: Wanted {"os":"win32", "arch":"any"} (Current:{"OS":"linux","arch":"x64"
```

Could you please give a work around for this.

I'm using that way
 const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8/issues/51) will help.